# Return false if string contains Unrecognized Escape sequence

Tags: c#

Is there a way to recognize if a string verbatim contains an Unrecognized escape sequence.
For example I have the following string input = @"abcd\x"; I need to write a function that checks if there is an unrecognized escape sequence and return false if it does.
I wrote the following function to check if there are escape sequences and return true, but it does not pass the above mentioned. It returns true if it contains escape sequences and fails to return false if it doesn't.  \x from the string @"abcd\x" would qualify as an unrecognized one(and any other example like this) Tried a lot of things but nothing seems to be working. Thank you in advance! (Sorry if there's a post related to this but I didn't stumbled upon it even though I tried to find something similar)

```
static bool ContainsEscapeSequence(string input)
    {
        if (input.Contains('\b') || input.Contains('\f') ||
            input.Contains('\n') || input.Contains('\r'))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (input.Contains('\t') || input.Contains('\"') ||
            input.Contains('\\') || input.Contains(@"\/"))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Something like `"\a\b\c\d\e\f"` won't compile, so I don't really understand what you're after. Escape sequences are when you're writing the c# code. Afterwards it gets turned into ascii/unicode characters. Escape sequences are validated at compile time.

Comment: Since you are testing a verbatim string, don't you want `input.Contains(@"\b")` and so on?  Escape sequences are processing inside character literals just like in non-verbatim strings.

Comment: Right now you are surely matching `input.Contains('\\')` for too many of your test cases -- @"\\" will match but so will @"\a" and @"\x" and @"\!".  Change to looking for `input.Contains(@"\\")` and things will be slightly better.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion for using @"\b". But is still, I have to return false if it isn't escape char. Will work from this suggestion onwards.

Comment: Use a regular expression to pull slash followed by a character into a capturing group, then check whether the captured match is one of a list of known slash-blahblah strings. If it isn't, raise an error

Comment: If you can't work out the Regex, string split on slash instead and look at the first char of every string after the first in the resulting array